# Globally repurpose play/pause software buttons for all android media apps?

Tags: java, android

I began creating an app that will run in the background and globally repurposes the play/pause/forward/backward buttons to change the volume which is intended to apply to any media player.

Example: While streaming media in Pandora or Youtube, pressing pause will 
lower the volume then activate pause and pressing play will increase the volume then activate play.

I find that `onMediaButtonEvent()` will give me a similar effect except that this is localized to only within the app it is written in and applies to only physical hardware play/pause/forward/backward buttons.

Also, I can use `onClick()` which allows me to decide what happens when a play/pause/forward/backward button is pressed but this is limited to within the app.

Can anyone offer any insight on if there is another function, a work around or if this is even possible? Maybe i am looking in the wrong direction and there is something that needs to be modified in the kernel which is out of bounds.

Comment: I think what you are attempting is impossible. Due to security reasons alone, its not possible to access events in other apps in such a way.

Comment: How do you intend to universally identify "play/pause/forward/backward" buttons? If it is by icon, how do you intend to programmatically identify icons contained in other app's UIs? Also, do you think that every app ever written that has a button with a "play" icon is a media player? If your identification is by widget ID, do you think that every media player app has  some particular widget ID for "play", and that no other apps use that widget ID?